# Committee selection:Where is my mistake?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, combinations

> There are $5$ boys and $6$ girls. A committee of $4$ is to be selected so that it must consist at least one boy and at least one girl?

I consider $1$ boy can be chosen in $5$ ways.

Also, consider $1$ girl can be chosen in $6$ ways.

So, others $2$ can be chosen in $9C2$ ways.

So, required answer is $5 * 6 * 9C2$

But this is the wrong answer. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please read the ([tag:self-learning]) tag description more closely "The process of studying mathematics without formal instruction. Don't use this tag just because you were self-studying when you came across the mathematical question you're asking; it is only for when the fact that you're self-studying is what your question is about. "

Comment: You've overcounted. Let's number the boys B1-B5, and the girls G1-G6. Suppose you from the committee your way: we pick B3, then G2, then B5, then G3. But, you're counting separatedly the committee formed of B5, then G3, then B3, then G2.

Comment: Probably, for this question, it is easiest to consider the cases "1 boy, 3 girls" and "2 boys, 2 girls" and "3 boys, 1 girl" separately.

Comment: Alternatively you can count how many committees have no boys or have no girls  in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's denote the girls $\{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_6\}$ and the boys $\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_5\}$.

You count some configurations more than once. The selection $g_1,g_2,b_1,b_2$ is counted four times namely as
\begin{align*}
(g_1,b_1),(g_2,b_2)\\
(g_1,b_2),(g_2,b_1)\\
(g_2,b_1),(g_1,b_2)\\
(g_2,b_2),(g_1,b_1)
\end{align*}

> One way to count the number of admissible selections is: We select either one girl and three boys, or two girls and two boys or three girls and one boy giving
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{5}{1}\binom{6}{3}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{2}+\binom{5}{3}\binom{6}{1}&=20\cdot 5+ 10\cdot 15+ 10\cdot 6\\
> &=\color{blue}{310}
> \end{align*}

Another way:

> We count all selections of $4$ people and subtract the selections containing only girls and only boys giving
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{11}{4}-\binom{5}{4}-\binom{6}{4}&=330-5-15\\
> &=\color{blue}{310}
> \end{align*}